# java.lang.IllegalStateException View tree for androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView has no ViewTreeLifecycleOwner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting a crash that I don't know how to fix. Here's the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
View tree for androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{84020a3 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0741 app:id/pills_compose_view} has no ViewTreeLifecycleOwner
androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy$DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed.installFor (ViewCompositionStrategy.android.kt:153)

androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.setViewCompositionStrategy (ComposeView.android.kt:137)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.ProfileViewHolder.bind (ProfileViewHolder.kt:147)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.ProfileViewHolder.bind (ProfileViewHolder.kt:67)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment.setupViewHolder (SwipeFragment.kt:358)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment.setupViewHolder$default (SwipeFragment.kt:348)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment.handleSwipeOff (SwipeFragment.kt:185)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment.onViewSwiped (SwipeFragment.kt:87)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment.access$onViewSwiped (SwipeFragment.kt:39)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment$getViewForItemType$1.invoke (SwipeFragment.kt:406)
com.mutualapp.ui.fragments.SwipeFragment$getViewForItemType$1.invoke (SwipeFragment.kt:406)
com.mutualapp.ui.view.VerticalSwipeView.translationUpdater (VerticalSwipeView.kt:199)
com.mutualapp.ui.view.VerticalSwipeView._init_$lambda$0 (VerticalSwipeView.kt:51)
com.mutualapp.ui.view.VerticalSwipeView.$r8$lambda$xAMm1_P3o2NWcfU_6EyhQbJlqmM
com.mutualapp.ui.view.VerticalSwipeView$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationUpdate (Unknown Source:2)
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue (ValueAnimator.java:1653)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Here is the ProfileViewHolder code:

```
class ProfileViewHolder(private var context: Context,
                        private var swipeFragment: SwipeFragment?,
                        private var glide: RequestManager,
                        view: View,
                        clickListener: () -> Unit,
                        val longClickListener: (url: String) -> Unit,
                        private val swipePhotosListener: () -> Unit,
                        private val mainInteractor: SwipeFragment.InteractionListener) : SwipeFragment.ViewHolder<ProfileSwipeItem>(view) {

    private val pillComposeView = view.findViewById(R.id.pills_compose_view) as ComposeView

    override fun bind(swipeItem: ProfileSwipeItem, readyCallback: ((SwipeFragment.ViewHolder<ProfileSwipeItem>) -> Unit)?) {

         pillComposeView.apply {
                // Dispose of the Composition when the view's LifecycleOwner
                // is destroyed
                setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                ProfilePills()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is SwipeFragment.ViewHolder:

```
abstract class ViewHolder<in SI : SwipeItem>(val view: View) {
        var isRecyclable: Boolean = false
        abstract val swipeContent: VerticalSwipeView
        internal var deblurDuration = 300L

        abstract fun bind(swipeItem: SI, readyCallback: ((ViewHolder<SI>) -> Unit)? = null)
        abstract fun deblur()
        abstract fun blur()
    }
```

It's not crashing for everyone but it is crashing for a few users. Does anyone know how to fix this?